# OpenGL Orthographical Projection

Tags: opengl, matrix, transformation, projection, glm-math

I have been playing around with OpenGL and matrix operations and I understand the concept of P * V * M but I cannot understand why changing the Z position of the 'camera' does not have the effect of zooming.

When using a perspective projection, changing the Z of the camera has the effect of zoom (as i'd expect).

```
glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
glm::mat4 View       = glm::lookAt(
                            glm::vec3(0,0,3), // changing 3 to 8 will zoom out
                            glm::vec3(0,0,0),
                            glm::vec3(0,1,0)
                       );
glm::mat4 Model      = glm::mat4(1.0f);
gml::mat4 MVP        = Projection * View * Model;
```

However, when I use an ortho projection, changing the 3 to 8 or anything it does not have the effect of zooming out. I know they are very different projections but I am looking for an explanation (the math behind why it doesn't work would be especially helpful).

```
glm::mat4 Projection = glm::ortho(
    0.0f,
    128.0f,
    0.0f,
    72.0f,
    0.0f,
    100.0f
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how orthographic projections work. Let's start with a perspective transform:

You get the projection of an object by following a straight line to the camera:

[image]

If you move the camera closer, then you will see that the projected area increases:

[image]

Orthographic projections work differently. You get the projection by following a straight line that is perpendicular to the image plane:

[image]

And obviously, the size of the projected area does not depend on how far the camera is away from the object. That's because the projection lines will always be parallel and preserve the size of the object in the two directions of the image plane.

Comment: So the way to zoom an orthographic projection is just by changing the numbers passed into `glm::ortho`?

Answer (score 2):

When you change the Z coordinate from 3 to 8, you're not actually zooming out, you're just moving the camera farther away.  You can zoom out without moving the camera by changing the first parameter for `glm::perspective`.

An orthographic camera doesn't have a location (you can think of it as infinitely far away), so it's not possible to "move" an orthographic camera in the same way.  You can zoom out by changing the bounds passed to `glm::ortho`.  Simply pass larger numbers to `glm::ortho`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what happens, when you move perspective camera:

[image: perspective camera]

Here: (xe, ye, ze) - point in eye coordinate system. (xp, yp, zp) - projection of that point
n - distance to near plane
t - distance to top plane of frustrum

You can see, that when you approach camera, xp and yp will grow.

In contrast, changing z position of orthogonal camera won't effect xp and yp, but still will effect zp, thus will change value in depth buffer.

[image: orthogonal camera]

Comment: So the way to zoom an orthographic projection is just by changing the numbers passed into glm::ortho?